# Grouping By Month from String Date using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I am doing a lot of unnecessary work to `GroupBy` Records by Month. In the database, the Date is saved in `varchar` format and now, I can't change the format since lots of things are dependent on it. Following is my code:

```
var Job_Progress_ViewModel = new List<MyViewModel>();

var Job_Ids = new List<int?>();

var Jobs = db.Jobs.Where(x.Date != null).ToList();

foreach (var job in Jobs)
{
   int Year = Year_from_strDate(job.Date);
   if (Year == 2018)
   {
      Job_Ids .Add(order.Id);
   }
}

var JobProgress = db.JobProgress.Where(x => Job_Ids.Contains(x.JobId)).ToList();

foreach(var record in JobProgress)
{
   var Model = new MyViewModel()
   {
       Month = Month_From_strDate(record.Job.Date),
       Amount = record.total
   };
   Job_Progress_ViewModel.Add(Model);
}
```

And in my View:

```
foreach (var month in Model.Select(x=>x.Month).Distinct())
{
   <tr>
     <td>
        @Model.Where(x => x.Month == month).Sum(x => x.Amount))
     </td>
   </tr>
}
```

I don't think it is the good approach.Then I search on the internet, and tried following code:

```
db.JobProgress.Where(x => Job_Ids.Contains(x.JobId))
.GroupBy(x => Month_From_strDate(x.Job.Date)
.Select(ln => new MyViewModel
{
   Month = // How can I add month Here,
   Amount = ln.Sum(r => r.total)
}).ToList();
```

I find it better approach but here are two problems:

1. I don't know how to get Month,
2. And I can't use Date Conversion Function. I am getting following error which is valid:

> LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()'

How can I tackle this problem since I can't change date format in my database?

Comment: What format is the date in the `varchar`?

Comment: It is `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the `datetime` as `varchar` in the database is extremely bad idea. It would be very hard to manage them and it gives you headache like this example. So, I strongly suggest you to convert it to `datetime` type at any cost.

So, in your case you can try to use `SqlFunctions.DateAdd` to parse `varchar` to `datetime` and `group` them by using `SqlFunctions.DatePart`.

```
db.JobProgress.Where(x => Job_Ids.Contains(x.JobId))
.GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("month", SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0, x.Job.Date)))
.Select(ln => new MyViewModel
{
   Month = ln.Key
   Amount = ln.Sum(r => r.total)
}).ToList();
```

If you get failed about parsing datetime, you should materialize the query first and apply group by in-memory and this approach would be expensive.

**Note :** `SqlFunctions.DateAdd` accepts string date parameter, you can review the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.dateadd(v=vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT**

If you want to apply parsing date and grouping actions in-memory, you could refactor your code like this;

```
db.JobProgress.Where(x => Job_Ids.Contains(x.JobId))
.Select(x => new {DateStr = x.Job.Date,Total = x.total}).ToList()
.GroupBy(x => new{ Year = Year_from_strDate(DateStr), Month = Month_From_strDate(DateStr)})
.Select(ln => new MyViewModel
{
   Year = ln.Key.Year,
   Month = ln.Key.Month,
   Amount = ln.Sum(r => r.Total)
}).ToList();
```

Also, I don't know what is the `Year_from_strDate` and `Month_From_strDate` methods but I assume that you can parse datetime successfully with these methods.

Comment: The reason I am storing in string format is my application supports multi-culture. How can I always store the date in English format without converting it to string? I don't want to use `SQLFunctions` here. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: In that case, you should materialize the query first and apply parse in-memory. Then group by month.

Comment: Could you help me with it? I need to minimize the code. It is very ugly.

Comment: I will try. `Year_from_strDate` and `Month_From_strDate` these are functions to get year and month part from `string` date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166729/discussion-between-ashir-k-and-lucky).